# SetServiceStatus sets SERVICE_STOPPED, but QueryServiceStatusEx returns SERVICE_STOP_PENDING

Tags: winapi, service

I've stumbled upon a serious issue in my service/client program, which works in the following way:

- The client app uses `ControlService(... SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP ...)` to stop the service.
- While the service is stopping, the app periodically calls `QueryServiceStatusEx` to check whether `dwCurrentState` is `SERVICE_STOPPED`. It also checks `dwWaitHint` for a timeout.

Meanwhile the service does this:

- Before cleaning up, it calls `SetServiceStatus` with `dwCurrentState` = `SERVICE_STOP_PENDING` and `dwWaitHint` = `3000`.
- After cleaning up, it calls `SetServiceStatus` with `dwCurrentState` = `SERVICE_STOPPED` and `dwWaitHint` = `0`.

After reproducing and logging the issue I came up with this:

Everything works as expected **except** the last time when the client calls `QueryServiceStatusEx`, which returns `dwCurrentState` = `SERVICE_STOP_PENDING` and `dwWaitHint` = `0`! That makes it behave as if the operation timed out.

I don't know how this can even happen, I can clearly see in the logs that the service sets `dwCurrentState` = `SERVICE_STOPPED` before exiting.

Is it a known issue? Do you have any clue what might be happening here?

**Update:**

Here's the logs of the client app:

```
24437 ssStatus.dwWaitHint: 3000, ssStatus.dwCurrentState: 3
24546 ssStatus.dwWaitHint: 0, ssStatus.dwCurrentState: 3
24609 ssStatus.dwWaitHint: 0, ssStatus.dwCurrentState: 3
...
26000 ssStatus.dwWaitHint: 0, ssStatus.dwCurrentState: 3
26062 ssStatus.dwWaitHint: 0, ssStatus.dwCurrentState: 3
26218 Stopped
```

As you can see, the service has stopped between 24437 and 24546 (`GetTickCount`), and it's state was changed at 26218. Which means it was flagged as `SERVICE_STOP_PENDING` for additional 1,672 seconds. Can it be that Windows changes it's state? Why was it flagged as pending for so long?

**Update 2:**

More observations:

- calling `SetServiceStatus` affects everything except `dwCurrentState`, which is left as `SERVICE_STOP_PENDING` as long as the process of the service is running. Is that a feature of Windows? Is it documented?
- My service process is left hanging for more than a second after returning from `LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION` and before returning from `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher`. Why is that happening? (P.S. it happens upon booting Windows).
- Trying to write to the service executable sometimes returns `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`, even though it's state is `SERVICE_STOPPED`. Is there a reliable method to make sure the process is ended completely?

Can anybody explain these? Raymond Chen?

**Update 3:**

More interesting information: `QueryServiceStatusEx` returns dwWaitHint: 0, dwCurrentState: 3, dwCheckPoint: 0 even if I never set `dwWaitHint` and `dwCheckPoint` to zero! What's going on here?

Comment: Well, nothing you can do about it so just punt the problem.  dwWaitHint has no meaning for the stopped state so just don't change it.

Comment: That's what MS are doing in their [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ("ReportSvcStatus( SERVICE_STOPPED, NO_ERROR, 0 );"), and my app is based on it, hence the behavior. I did some additional logging, and updated the question.

Comment: I suspect your service is doing some work between setting the status to SERVICE_STOPPED and ServiceMain exiting.  Maybe you have a pile of state rooted in a local variable in your ServiceMain function, so it's being cleaned up in a destructor when the function has apparently finished?

Comment: @arx no, that's not the case. I write in plain C, so no destructors there. Seems like the delay only happens if the client stops the service right after system boot. Maybe the system is busy with booting, and that's the reason for the delay, but I can't understand why `QueryServiceStatusEx` returns wired values. For now, I've special-cased `dwWaitHint` == `0`, but it's really interesting to know what's going on here.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was assuming that Windows only reports that the service has stopped when the thread has actually exited, regardless of what the service tells it, but that it is correctly reporting the last hint value.  This could be tested by adding a deliberate delay before the thread exits, and by setting the hint to a sentinel value.  If your thread is starved between setting the status and the thread terminating (because the system is very busy during boot) this would explain what you are seeing.

Comment: I tried it on a simple service, and `QueryServiceStatusEx` returned `SERVICE_STOPPED` right after the service set it, even though the service called `Sleep(1000)` before terminating. So maybe I've just discovered a bug in Windows? I couldn't find the behavior documented anywhere.

Comment: You're right.  I tried it myself and Windows doesn't even wait for the service thread to exit.  As soon as the status is set to SERVICE_STOPPED, the main thread exits and the process terminates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple service and tried querying the service state from the service itself so that the queries were synchronised with the changes in state.

The SCM asked the service to stop.  The queried state was SERVICE_RUNNING.  The service set the state to SERVICE_STOPPED, queried it again and got SERVICE_STOP_PENDING (with a wait hint of 0).  Finally, the service queried the state after StartServiceCtrlDispatcher returned and got SERVICE_STOPPED.

This isn't entirely consistent; there are two possible outcomes for the three queries:

SERVICE_RUNNING, SERVICE_STOP_PENDING and SERVICE_STOPPED or

SERVICE_RUNNING, SERVICE_STOPPED and SERVICE_STOPPED.

I see the same thing with the `sc` command-line tool.  If I ask it to stop my service it sometimes reports the state as stopped and sometimes reports it as pending, even though my service never sets it to pending.

There is a brief window of SERVICE_STOP_PENDING immediately after the service sets the state to SERVICE_STOPPED, but before Windows returns control to the dispatcher (main) thread.  If the machine is booting and thus busy this window of SERVICE_STOP_PENDING could be quite long.

The behaviour is reproducible and seems to be deliberate.  But, as you say, it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis. I guess the best solution here is to be defensive - I no longer consider `dwWaitHint` as a timeout value, only as a delay hint. It sucks that I have to discover these nuances the hard way. I mean, my code was based on examples from MSDN. Where should I expect to get correct snippets, if not MSDN?